# Name of the font used for code snippets on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, fonts

Which font is used on Stack Overflow for code snippets?

Example:

```
var $div = $("#preloader");
$.each($.imgNames, function (i, val) {
    $("<img />").attr("src", $.largePath + val).addClass('PRELOADED').appendTo($div);
});
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It depends what fonts are available on your system, but the list (in order of priority) is:

Consolas, Menlo, Monaco, Lucida Console, Liberation Mono, DejaVu Sans Mono, Bitstream Vera Sans Mono, Courier New, monospace, serif

You can see this by inspecting one of the `pre` or `code` elements that contain formatted code (screenshot from Chrome's DOM inspector):

[image]

For more information on how that CSS behaves, you could look at the [CSS Fonts module specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#font-family-prop).

Answer (score 4):

As of May 10, 2021 the font Stack Overflow, Inc. uses on Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange is as follows:

> | OS | Sans | Mono |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | macOS | San Francisco | San Francisco Mono |
> | iOS | San Francisco | San Francisco Mono |
> | Windows | Segoe UI | Consolas, or Cascadia Mono, Segoe UI Mono if you've installed those manually |
> | Ubuntu | Ubuntu | Ubuntu Mono |
> | Android | Roboto | Roboto Mono |
> | Chrome OS | Roboto | Roboto Mono |
> | Fallback | `sans-serif` | Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, `monospace` |

From *[We are switching to system fonts on May 10, 2021](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/364048)*